# Slim Error in Dependencies Cannot Find Controller

Tags: php, slim

I'm getting Slim Application Error:

```
Class 'Slim\App\Controllers\MainController' not found
```

This seems to be the same as others posts except, they don't have the 'Slim' in front.  I think that's why it is failing.

project structure

```
/src
    /Controllers
        MainController.php
    /vendor
    /public
        index.php
```

composer.json

```
{
"require": {
    "slim/slim": "^3.12"
},

"autoload": {
    "psr-4" : {
        "App\\" : "src/"
    }
}
```

}

index.php

```
use \Psr\Http\Message\ServerRequestInterface as Request;
use \Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface as Response;

require '../vendor/autoload.php';

$configuration = [
    'settings' => [
    'displayErrorDetails' => true,
],
];
$c = new \Slim\Container($configuration);
$app = new \Slim\App($c);

require_once('../settings.php');
require_once('../dependencies.php');
require_once('../routes.php');

$app->run();
```

dependencies.php

```
use Slim\App;
use Slim\Container;
use App\Controllers;

$container = $app->getContainer();

$container['MainController'] = function ($c)
{
    return new App\Controllers\MainController;
};
```

/src/Controllers/MainController.php

```
namespace App\Controllers;
use \Psr\Http\Message\ServerRequestInterface as Request;
use \Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface as Response;

class MainController
{
public function search(Request $request, Response $response, $args)
{
    $response->write("Hello");

    return $response;
}
}
```

Comment: In dependencies.php `use App\Controllers;` should change to `use App\Controllers\MainController;`, then in `$container['MainController']` definition you should `return new MainController;` or `return new \App\Controllers\MainController;`.

Comment: that didn't work

Answer (score 0):

Always use the full class name for the container id.

Example

```php
use App\Controllers\MainController;
// ...

$container[MainController::class] = function ($c)
{
    return new MainController();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In **dependencies.php** you've written `use App\Controllers;` and `App\Controllers` is a namespace not a class name. You need to name a class when using `use` keyword, like what you did in `use Slim\App;` or `use \Psr\Http\Message\ServerRequestInterface as Request;`.

Here is a modified version of your code that works as expected:

**index.php**

```
<?php
require __DIR__ . '/../vendor/autoload.php';

use \Psr\Http\Message\ServerRequestInterface as Request;
use \Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface as Response;
use Slim\App;
use Slim\Container;
use App\Controllers\MainController;

$app = new \Slim\App;
$container = $app->getContainer();

$container['MainController'] = function ($c)
{
    return new MainController;
};

$app->get('/', 'MainController');

$app->run();
```

**src/Controllers/MainContrloller.php**

```
<?php
namespace App\Controllers;
use \Psr\Http\Message\ServerRequestInterface as Request;
use \Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface as Response;

class MainController
{
    public function __invoke(Request $request, Response $response, $args)
    {
        $response->write("Hello");

        return $response;
    }
}
```